# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException: null in DynamoDB

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am working with DynamoDB, I am extracting the information of my table "orders" correctly but I just have problems with one.

For example, if I want to get the userID, I got it correctly doing that:

```
String user_idp = item.get("user").getM().get("user_id").getS();
```

But if I want get the same for other field called provider I got java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
String pr = item.get("provider").getM().get("name").getS();
```

The error that I got is:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Here is the structure:

```
  "provider": {
    "address": "someadress",
    "name": "somename",
    "phoneNumber": somePhoneNumber,
    "provider_id": "someProviderId"
  }
```

[image]

I am missing something with DynamoDB, can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you check in debug if it's null the get of provider (is the correct name, right?) or the get of name? What's your table structure?

Comment: Hi @MatteoZanini thank for your answer, yes I have checked all that you said and I added a picture in the description.

Comment: It seems everything's ok, so which part result null, in debug? Are you sure that's the row throwing the exception?

Comment: Hi, yes completely sure, this is the weird thing here.

Comment: Then it could be the item object null, try to check every part of that row, doing the same logic in more rows, or in debug, to see which part is null

Comment: Hi, I just resolved, it was a dumb mistake.... ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(orders").withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated).withAttributesToGet("provider"); I forgot insert the AttributesToGet. I am dumb :). Thanks for your help.